# How do I extract the information from the website?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to gather information of all the vessels from this website:
https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/data/?asset_type=vessels&columns=flag,shipname,photo,recognized_next_port,reported_eta,reported_destination,current_port,imo,ship_type,show_on_live_map,time_of_latest_position,lat_of_latest_position,lon_of_latest_position&ship_type_in|in|Cargo%20Vessels|ship_type_in=7

This is my code right now:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

url = "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/data/?asset_type=vessels&columns=flag,shipname,photo,recognized_next_port,reported_eta,reported_destination,current_port,imo,ship_type,show_on_live_map,time_of_latest_position,lat_of_latest_position,lon_of_latest_position&ship_type_in|in|Cargo%20Vessels|ship_type_in=7"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\CSA\OneDrive - College Sainte-Anne\Programming\PYTHON\Learning\WS\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get(url)

browser.implicitly_wait(100)
Vessel_link = browser.find_element_by_class_name("ag-cell-content-link")
Vessel_link.click()

browser.implicitly_wait(30)
imo = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="imo"]')
print(imo)
```

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNaUc.png)

I am using selenium, which isn't going to work because. I have several thousands of ships to extract data from and it just isn't going to be efficient. (Also, I only need to extract information from Cargo Vessels (U can find that using the filter or by looking at green signs on the vessel type column.) and I need to extract the country name(flag), the Imo and the Vessels name.

What should I use? Selenium or Bs4 + requests or other libraries? And How? I just started web scraping...

I can't get the Imo nor anything! The HTML structure is very weird.

I would appreciate any help. Thank You! :)

Comment: They sell that information via API. Even if you could scrape it now, it might not work in some hours. You might want to either pay and use the APIs or find your information from another source: https://mods.marin.nl/display/MIOD/AIS+Data+Sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of clicking each vessel to open up the details, you can get the information you're searching for from the results page.  This will get each vessel, pull the info you wanted and click to the next page if there are more vessels:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

url = "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/data/?asset_type=vessels&columns=flag,shipname,photo,recognized_next_port,reported_eta,reported_destination,current_port,imo,ship_type,show_on_live_map,time_of_latest_position,lat_of_latest_position,lon_of_latest_position&ship_type_in|in|Cargo%20Vessels|ship_type_in=7"

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\CSA\OneDrive - College Sainte-Anne\Programming\PYTHON\Learning\WS\chromedriver_win32 (1)\')
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

checking_for_vessels = True
vessel_count = 0

while checking_for_vessels:
    vessel_left_container = browser.find_element_by_class_name('ag-pinned-left-cols-container')
    vessels_left = vessel_left_container.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[role="row"]')

    vessel_right_container = browser.find_element_by_class_name("ag-body-container")
    vessels_right = vessel_right_container.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[role="row"]')

    for i in range(len(vessels_left)):
        vessel_count += 1
        vessel_country_list = vessels_left[i].find_elements_by_class_name('flag-icon')

        if len(vessel_country_list) == 0:
            vessel_country = 'Unknown'
        else:
            vessel_country = vessel_country_list[0].get_attribute('title')

        vessel_name = vessels_left[i].find_element_by_class_name('ag-cell-content-link').text
        vessel_imo = vessels_right[i].find_element_by_css_selector('[col-id="imo"] .ag-cell-content div').text

        print('Vessel #' + str(vessel_count) + ': ' + vessel_name + ', ' + vessel_country + ', ' + vessel_imo)

    pagination_container = browser.find_element_by_class_name('MuiTablePagination-actions')
    page_number = pagination_container.find_element_by_css_selector('input').get_attribute('value')
    max_page_number = pagination_container.find_element_by_class_name('MuiFormControl-root').get_attribute('max')

    if page_number == max_page_number:
        checking_for_vessels = False
    else:
        next_page_button = pagination_container.find_element_by_css_selector('button[title="Next page"]')
        next_page_button.click()
```

There was one vessel that did not display a flag, so there's a check for that and the country is replaced with 'Unknown' if no flag found.  The same kind of check can be done for the vessel name and imo.

The implicit wait was reduced to 5 because of the known issue of missing a flag on one vessel and waiting 100 seconds for this to be figured out was excessive.  This number can be adjusted higher if you find there's issues waiting long enough to find elements.

It appears you are using a windows machine.  You can place the path of your chromedriver in the PATH variable on your machine and then you don't have to use the path when you instantiate your browser driver.  Obviously, your path to your chromedriver is different than mine, so hopefully what you provided is correct or else this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I like to work with [bs4](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe/) but I think this [info](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/) will help to.